# How to print _r selected array?

Tags: php

```
Jcart Object(
    [config] => Array
        (
            [jcartPath] => jcart/
            [checkoutPath] => checkout.php
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [id] => my-item-id
                    [name] => my-item-name
                    [price] => my-item-price
                    [qty] => my-item-qty
                    [url] => my-item-url
                    [add] => my-add-button
                )

            [paypal] => Array
                (
                    [id] => seller_1282188508_biz@conceptlogic.com
                    [https] => 1
                    [sandbox] => 
                    [returnUrl] => 
                    [notifyUrl] => 
                )

            [currencyCode] => USD
            [csrfToken] => 
            [text] => Array
                (
                    [cartTitle] => Shopping Cart
                    [singleItem] => Item
                    [multipleItems] => Items
                    [subtotal] => Subtotal
                    [update] => update
                    [checkout] => checkout
                    [checkoutPaypal] => Checkout with PayPal
                    [removeLink] => remove
                    [emptyButton] => empty
                    [emptyMessage] => Your cart is empty!
                    [itemAdded] => Item added!
                    [priceError] => Invalid price format!
                    [quantityError] => Item quantities must be whole numbers!
                    [checkoutError] => Your order could not be processed!
                )

            [button] => Array
                (
                    [checkout] => 
                    [paypal] => 
                    [update] => 
                    [empty] => 
                )

            [tooltip] => 1
            [decimalQtys] => 
            [decimalPlaces] => 1
            [priceFormat] => Array
                (
                    [decimals] => 2
                    [dec_point] => .
                    [thousands_sep] => ,
                )

        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => poslaju
        )

    [names] => Array
        (
            [3] => Hockey Stick
            [poslaju] => Pos Laju
        )

    [prices] => Array
        (
            [3] => 33.25
            [poslaju] => 6.00
        )

    [qtys] => Array
        (
            [3] => 1
            [poslaju] => 3
        )

    [urls] => Array
        (
            [3] => http://bing.com
            [poslaju] => 
        )

    [subtotal] => 51.25
    [itemCount] => 4
)
```

Im using `print_r($jcart)` to get the result above. 
i just want to print out `[qtys]` array. i have try `print_r($qtys);` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the array element. So you'll always need to point to `$jcart` and then reference from there. As Sergey pointed out, you've got an object there

> Jcart Object

So you'll have to reference the element of the object, not an array

```
print_r($jcart->qtys);
```

Comment: Seems like `$jcart` is instance of `Jcart`, so probably reference should be  `$jcart->qtys`?

Comment: @SergeyChizhik Ah, so it is. I missed that on the first read.

Answer (score 1):

use the reference key for selecting that particular element u need.

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($jcart->qtys);
```

`<pre>` tag is just added to view the array in a better format

Comment: You'll have to add `true` to the `print_r` to concatenate it like this